# Unable to create folder from batch file run by C#

Tags: c#, batch-file

I am having a batch file, which when runs independently creates a folder. But when I run the same batch file using C# code, I don't get anything. 
I am not sure how to debug this.

I checked the path of the batch file it's right.

**C# code**

```
string startupPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
string bat = startupPath+@"\batch.bat";
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
psi.Verb = "runas"; 
psi.Arguments = "/C " + bat;
Process.Start(psi);
```

**Batch file**

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO.


cd C:\Users\rftx47\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\CertiHelper\CertiHelper
mkdir folderA

ECHO.
PAUSE
CLS
EXIT
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why not ``Process.Start(bat);`` ? Or ``psi.FileName = bat;``

Comment: I think in that case , command prompt won't run in admin mode. I needed admin mode.

Comment: Where is the content of the batch file? Where is `startupPath`?

Comment: Or ``psi.FileName = bat;``

Comment: The batch file will not have the environmental variables so PATH will not be recognized.  Make sure all executable's in batch have full path names.

Comment: *What am I missing?* Quotes around the folder name in your call to `cd` that are required because of the spaces in the name.

Comment: You may want to ensure the file path has quotes around it if the path has spaces like it does in your example Batch file

Comment: Why exactly are you not just using c# to create the folder?

Comment: @IamBatman creating folder isn't the only task, it's just the first step.

Comment: @KenWhite: tried, still not working and Process.Start(bat) works. But I want cmd in admin mode.

Comment: Then you've not posted your actual code, because that's the only issue that your batch file contains (unless `C:\Users\rftx47` or any other part of that directory doesn't exist, which we can't see from where we're sitting).

Comment: when I run the batch file from outside, it works fine though. So, not a problem with batch file.

Comment: Do you run the batch file from outside using `runas cmd.exe /c batchname.bat`?

Comment: I should have tried that first. I was running it clicking on it! Will try that!

Comment: @KenWhite, runas.exe uses the Secondary Logon service to create a process as another user. This service does not support UAC elevation. The shell's "runas" verb uses the Application Information service, which supports elevating a restricted admin or getting alternate admin credentials via the consent dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doing exactly as it's supposed to, it's running the command console and then closing it.  Exactly how you wrote it.  I refactored it for you below.

```
            string startupPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string bat = startupPath+@"\batch.bat";;
            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.FileName = @bat;  //this is where you need to put the file name.
            psi.Verb = "runas";
            psi.Arguments = "/c ";
            psi.UseShellExecute = true;  //this is where you start cmd
            Process.Start(psi);
```